# Does the internet connection disconnect when the public IP is changing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dns, ip

My question is : does the internet connection disconnect when the public IP is changing ?

To be more clear: I am going to connect my clients' application to my server by Dynamic DNS, so I am wondering about the moment of IP changing if they will lose their connection with server or not.

If yes, could you please advise me ? :)

Note: It's about SQL Server 2008 and (free dnsdynamic or paid no-ip)

Thank you a lot.

Comment: yes. it's like moving to a new house. people going to the old house won't find you there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the IP might change during an ongoing connection? I mean, in my experience with my Internet provider, the dynamic IP only ever changes when the router is restarted and reconnects to the provider. In those situations, like power outage, disconnected cable etc., all connections are obviously disconnected. This is true even when using static IP.

So I would advise you do not worry about dynamic IP, but solve how the client is going to reconnect after a total disconnection of your server. This would in my experience cover also all IP changes.

Comment: Hmmmm, i am not sure but i know that every IP address would change if it's not static even if the router is working always. it maybe change every 6 hours

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to think about the problem.

Most communication is ip-based traffic, it goes from a source-ip to a destination ip (tcp/udp also uses port numbers). Your traffic will be interrupted if anything changes.

However, you should not expose private services over a public network, but instead tunnel them within a vpn-connection. This connection will be interrupted when your ip-address changes, but the private network addresses will remain static, depending on configuration. An actual disconnection on the private connection will not be seen until the tcp connection has issued a few resends and determined that the connection is down. There are several parameters available on both [windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170359) and [linux](http://www.speedguide.net/articles/linux-tcpip-parameters-reference-2672) to configure the details.

You mention a client side application, and I doubt there is a easy way to solve the issue with bad network connections. I'm thinking a [CQRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) inspired architecture with heavy read caching and a outgoing buffer for commands. That would allow you to present old (cached) data when your connection is down, while storing any user commands given to send them when your connection is available again.